# Is two years without a referee report normal?

Tags: soft-question, journals

Firstly,  the [help page](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic) for Mathoverflow does not forbid asking such a question. Secondly I found a [similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114344/13-months-and-not-even-one-report-what-would-you-do) on Mathoverflow and thirdly as far as I know, waiting for two years for a referee report is unheard of outside mathematics. So, here I go:

I submitted a 25-page paper to a pretty good journal exactly two years ago. I say "pretty good" so it is not a journal like Inventions or Annals. In these two years I've contacted the journal's contact person as well as the designated editor, without any avail. The last thing they told me was that "Since the
start of 2014 we have sent it out to six new reviewers and are hopeful a
report will be received soon."
Let me make my questions precise:

**Question 1:** Does a journal have a *responsibility* to give a referee report to an author? Do I have any rights as an author?

Also because this is NOT the first time this happens to me:

**Question 2:** Is there any advice for not-waiting-two-years-for-a-report next time?

Comment: First, this must be a **VERY** good journal: sending a paper to six referees at once---this is what is really unheard of! Second, as an author, you have the right to withdraw the paper; then you are free to resubmit it to another place. In my opinion, 2 years is indeed way too much!

Comment: This kind of thing is hard to control.  The average time to get a report for my papers seems to be about a year, but on many occasions is has taken longer.  After a year has past, my usual practice is to ping the editor every 2 months.  Other than that, there is not much you can do.  Certainly getting angry is not likely to have much of an effect.

Comment: It happened to me too. After two years, the editor sent me back the paper without referee, saying that they were sorry to not accepting papers because of a long backlog.

Comment: Nothing is unheard of on this subject (I could share some horror stories, but it would probably bore most folks here as they've experienced similar things themselves). Stay calm and polite, and you can always withdraw and resubmit to a different journal.

Comment: This  is not uncommon and there is not much that you can do. It's important not to get discouraged  because it happens to other people, including myself. Be persistent!

Comment: I find the fact that they have tried six different referees a lot more impressive than the two year wait. A lot of editors might have given up by now. You might want to chat briefly with the editor by phone to see if there is anything you can do to help move things along faster. People aren't always willing to reveal too much in an email.

Comment: Although you have already got some insightful comments and answers here, your question fits better in http://academia.stackexchange.com.

Comment: See also my question which is related to your problem at the following page:  http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/8574/4511

Comment: I am wondering how things ended. I just got a rejection from a top journal after submitting to it for 8 months. I didn't get any report. They said "your interesting paper should certainly be published but we receive many excellent papers so we have to make hard decisions''. They also said it took so much time because of the MOVE of the editorial office. However, I can see papers were published during this 8 months.    Unbelievable!  Being rejected is normal. However, the reason they gave me is really terrible.

Comment: OK, you’re completely right, tomorrow I’ll start reviewing the paper!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two years without a report or decision is certainly too long. But this happens sometimes
for various reasons.

The journals do not have to show you the referee's reports. At least some journals
say that they don't have to. And that this is their policy. So a paper can be rejected
(or accepted) without a referee report shown to the author.

If the reason of such delay is that the editor cannot find a referee, you may try to
suggest him/her several possible referees. Sometimes the editors ask themselves.
S/he may follow your suggestion or not, but try to suggest as many as you can,
so that s/he has a choice.

I also recommend posting all your papers on arxiv. Besides many other advantages, you worry
less about how long will it take to publish.

Comment: I put them on Arxiv first however peer reviewed and published papers count more than preprints.

Comment: But at least this is an excellent way to secure your priority.